# How should the answers on the question about Throne card be handled?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, closing-questions, up-votes

This question about the [Throne card from the Deck of Many Things](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99012/how-does-the-throne-card-work) has attracted three answers which all say the same thing. That is, all three answers are duplicates of each other.

How should the Stack vote for these answers, and should the question be closed for attracting them? What is the normal policy for this scenario?

Comment: Is there a reason you are concerned that voting won't resolve this? They appear to all have been posted at about the same time.  Three great minds thinking alike, as it were.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's just a confusing scenario. It seems like they should all have the same scores, being the same answers.

Comment: I guess that the voters respond to the answers in a variable fashion, so maybe there's an anydice program we could create to predict that kind of behavior. 8^D  We've had a lot of discussions with how voting is done versus "should" be done (you can search a number of nvoigt's question and answers on meta so see a few of those) but in the end, voters vote as their mood moves them.  This seems a victimless crime, if there is anything wrong.

Comment: I think it will go down to how someone explained it - which will be helpful for anyone when formulating answers.

Comment: To illustrate that principle, @markovchain, I just went and looked at all three again, and each says the same thing in a slightly different, and correct, way.  So I upvoted all three, but I am very tempted to down vote the question as this poster seems (based on a few other questoins) to be equating DnD with CRPGs that have canned quests/items in them.  But I'll hold off on that.  I am trying to recall a q and a that might help the querent get an idea about that.

Comment: seems to me that "voters vote as the mood moves them" is a feature. Especially with many eyes, that's the best imaginable way to assess what answers will be good for later visitors (assuming the population of voters represents the population of visitors, which ANY voting scheme necessarily relies on).